# Jetpack Compose - Nested Scroll with ViewPager using AndroidView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

Here's my situation:

I have a screen with a [CollapsingToolbarScaffold](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar) and I need to implement a (not compose, so I can't use `HorizontalPager`) ViewPager on this screen. Each ViewPager page is a list with an infinite scroll feature implemented. I'm using the ScrollableTabRow composable for tabs.

The screen is all implemented, but I'm facing issues with the scrolling.

`CollapsingToolbarScaffold` lib recommends to set `verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` to the parent Column of my content. This works fine, but the ViewPager height doesn't seem to be calculated, making the scroll not happen. After some research, I found that we need to set the height explicitly if I want to use `verticalScroll`, but I couldn't make it work.

Here's what I've already tried:

1. Wrap the content in `BoxWithConstraints` and set the maxHeight;
2. Implement `onGloballyPositioned` modifier;
3. Set `scrollable(rememberScrollState(), Orientation.Vertical)`
4. Set `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(this, true)` to the ViewPager (this works, but the scroll gets no smooth at all so, certainly not an option).

Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
val selectedPage = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = selectedPage.value)

    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color(0xFFF1F3F5)) {

        Column {
            ScrollableTabRow(
                edgePadding = 0.dp,
                selectedTabIndex = selectedPage.value,
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .height(36.dp),
                indicator = { },
                divider = { }
            ) {
                NativeTab("Tab 1", 0, pagerState, selectedPage)
                NativeTab("Tab 2", 1, pagerState, selectedPage)
                NativeTab("Tab 3", 2, pagerState, selectedPage)
            }

            AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    ViewPager(context).also {
                        it.adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(context)
                        it.currentItem = selectedPage.value
                        it.addOnPageChangeListener(object :
                            ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
                            override fun onPageScrolled(
                                position: Int,
                                positionOffset: Float,
                                positionOffsetPixels: Int
                            ) {
                            }

                            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                                selectedPage.value = position
                            }

                            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                            }
                        })
                        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(it, true)
                    }
                },
                update = {
                    it.currentItem = selectedPage.value
                },
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks